# Grouped products, how to config childrens + increase and - decrease qty function correctly?

Tags: magento2, product, php, javascript, grouped-products

I have a problem with + increase and - decrease qty function. On 1 single click it goes up +2 or -2. It also do so on other children products qty inputs. How can I fix this correcly?

[image]

\Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository'); ?>

<?php $grouped = $_product->load($_product->getId()); ?>                    
<?php $associatedProducts = $grouped->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($grouped); ?>

</form>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="image-width"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Image') ?></th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Description') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $childProduct = $productRepository->get($_item->getSku()); ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="image-float"><img src="<?= $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$childProduct->getImage() ?>" alt width="230"/></td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><span class="sku"><?= $_item->getSku() ?></span></a>
                    <div class="price-font" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                     </div>
                    </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                            <div class="control qty">
                                <form data-product-sku="<?php echo $_item->getSku() ?>" data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">                                  
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item"  value="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" />
                                    
                                    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?><div class="box-tocart"><div class="fieldset"><div class="field qty"><div class="control">
                                    
                                    <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Antall" class="qty-default input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}"/>
                                    <span class="qty-main">
                    <span class="qty-btn qty-inc"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span class="qty-btn qty-dec"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </span>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    require(['jquery'], function(){
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery('.qty-inc').click(function () {
                                jQuery('.qty-default').val(Number(jQuery('.qty-default').val())+1);
                            });

                            jQuery('.qty-dec').click(function () {
                                    var value = Number(jQuery('.qty-default').val())-1;
                                    if(value > 0){
                                        jQuery('.qty-default').val(value);
                                    }

                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="actions">
                            <button type="submit" title="Legg i Handlekurv" class="action primary tocart" id="product-addtocart-button">
                            <span>Legg i Handlekurv</span>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>

<form>
```

**Edit:**
So after moving script from tbody to thead I fixed the +2 increase and -2 decrease from a single click. But the script is still adding +1 to all products when clicking + increase or - decrease.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    require(['jquery'], function(){
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery('.qty-inc').click(function () {
                                jQuery('.qty-default').val(Number(jQuery('.qty-default').val())+1);
                            });

                            jQuery('.qty-dec').click(function () {
                                    var value = Number(jQuery('.qty-default').val())-1;
                                    if(value > 0){
                                        jQuery('.qty-default').val(value);
                                    }

                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

**Edit:** Is this correct? When I click the button + or - nothing happens

```
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Antall" class="qty-default input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}"/>
                                    <span class="qty-main">
                    <span class="qty-btn qty-inc" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'+');"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span class="qty-btn qty-dec " href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'-');"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </span>
                <script>
                function qtyinc(element,action){
                    var oldVal = jQuery(element).parent().find("input").val();
                    if(isNaN(oldVal)){
                        jQuery(element).parent().find("input").val(1);
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(action == "+"){
                         if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 0 ) {
                            var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;
                            jQuery(element).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
                            jQuery(element).parent().find("input").trigger("change");

                            jQuery(element).parent().find("button").show();
                          }
                    }
                    if(action == "-"){                      
                        if(oldVal == 1 || oldVal == ''){                 
                            jQuery(element).parent().find("input").val(0);
                        }
                        if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 2 ) {
                            var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - 1;
                            jQuery(element).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
                            jQuery(element).parent().find("button").show();
                            jQuery(element).parent().find("input").trigger("change");
                        }
                    }
                }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer Below code. I have done it in my Project it's worked perfectly. you Need to Some changes to your code.

```
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Antall" class="qty-default input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}"/>
                                    <span class="qty-main">
                    <span class="qty-btn qty-inc" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'+');><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span class="qty-btn qty-dec " href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'-');><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </span>
```

Create a Below function and insert the function to the End of the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function qtyinc(element,action){
    var oldVal = jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").val();    
    if(isNaN(oldVal)){
        jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").val(1);
        return false;
    }
    if(action == "+"){

         if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 0 ) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;            
            jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").val(newVal);
            jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").trigger("change");            
          }
    }
    if(action == "-"){                      
        if(oldVal == 1 || oldVal == ''){                 
            jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").val(0);
        }
        if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 2 ) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - 1;
            jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").val(newVal);            
            jQuery(element).parents('.control.qty').find("input#qty").trigger("change");
        }
    }
 }      
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I edited my post with code. Could you please check what I am missing? When I click + or - nothing happens. It's likely script isn't being linked up or onclick command?

Comment: Is this really correct? onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'+'); onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'-');

Comment: this function call after the end of the file. I have updated the code so please replace it with a new code.

Comment: Thank you, It's working for me now. onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'+'); is also missing " on endline. onclick="qtyinc(jQuery(this),'+');" but after fixing that and adding script to end of file it's working. :)